# How do i revert to the first screen?

Tags: android

In my application grid view is loaded first. Selecting an image renders a linear layout view(second screen) . In the second screen some action is performed on click of a button.  Now what  i am curious to know how can i revert to the first screen from the second screen on click of that button?

I have tried `MoodJournal.this.finish();` but it goes to the home screen.

I have also tried `MoodJournal.this.setContentView(R.layout.main);` but it renders a blank screen.

Please help me on this

Thanks

Pankaj

Comment: from activty 1 --> activity 2, Did u finish your first screen/activity?

Comment: @zoombie thanks for replying actually i have created liner layout at run time  (on click of item in grid view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pankaj, if I understand correctly, you're not making a different Activity for each screen, which is the recommended way of doing things. That is to say, for the second screen it is not sufficient to "create a linear layout at runtime", you must write a new class that extends Activity and invoke it from the first screen by using the Intent mechanism, and apply that linear layout on it's onCreate(). If you do that, the screen stack is automatically managed for you.

There are plenty of tutorials on how to do this, but the basic idea you want to take with you is that IN GENERAL (there can be exceptions) one screen = one class that extends Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you call finish() in previous activities?

Comment: @LordTwaroogthanks for replying actually i have created liner layout at run time  (on click of item in grid view).

Comment: I would recommend putting LinearLayout in new Activity, sticking with rule "new screen = new Activity"

Comment: can you please send me the url of some example which i can study?

Comment: http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/